# Mount/Unmount USB drives with VBSCript

Tags: vbscript

I am looking for a way to mount\unmount a USB flash drive using VBScript.  This is the closest I was able to get.

```
Sub EjectDrive(strDrive)
On Error Resume Next
CONST SSF_DRIVES = 17
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objDrive = objShell.Namespace(SSF_DRIVES).ParseName(strDrive)
objDrive.InvokeVerb "E&ject"
End Sub
```

Comment: I would be interested in this in C# as well, if anyone has C# examples. In fact, they are probably quite similar.

Answer (score 2):

This will work on Windows Server 2003, but not NT/2000/XP/Vista unfortunately.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_Volume Where Name = 'E:\\'")

For Each objItem in colItems
    objItem.Dismount(True, True)
Next
```

From [Dismount a Volume](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/storage/disks/drives/stdvvb07.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [thread](http://www.winserverkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/windows-server-scripting/3654/Win32-Volume-dismount-method-failure), its talks about using the mountvol.exe command line tool to mount/unmount a drive, and it should work for USB flash drives, or there is also a program called deveject.  Se this thread for more info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/d2e5d16e-e7c9-48ef-88b8-3abf6e638384

Answer (score 0):

You can popup the eject dialog by using something like this.  I am not sure if it possible to unmount a specific device.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
intReturn = WshShell.Run("RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll", 1, TRUE)
```